# hello,I would like to move my satellite menu from top right corner to the bottom left corner of the screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have 2 java files
   this is the first one called ArcLayout

---

```
public class ArcLayout extends ViewGroup {
/**
 * children will be set the same size.
 */
private int mChildSize;

private int mChildPadding = 5;

private int mLayoutPadding = 10;

public static final float DEFAULT_FROM_DEGREES = 270.0f;

public static final float DEFAULT_TO_DEGREES = 360.0f;

private float mFromDegrees = DEFAULT_FROM_DEGREES;

private float mToDegrees = DEFAULT_TO_DEGREES;

private static final int MIN_RADIUS = 100;

/* the distance between the layout's center and any child's center */
private int mRadius;

private boolean mExpanded = false;

public ArcLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ArcLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArcLayout, 0, 0);
        mFromDegrees = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ArcLayout_fromDegrees, DEFAULT_FROM_DEGREES);
        mToDegrees = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ArcLayout_toDegrees, DEFAULT_TO_DEGREES);
        mChildSize = Math.max(a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ArcLayout_childSize, 0), 0);

        a.recycle();
    }
}

private static int computeRadius(final float arcDegrees, final int childCount, final int childSize,
        final int childPadding, final int minRadius) {
    if (childCount < 2) {
        return minRadius;
    }

    final float perDegrees = arcDegrees / (childCount - 1);
    final float perHalfDegrees = perDegrees / 2;
    final int perSize = childSize + childPadding;

    final int radius = (int) ((perSize / 2) / Math.sin(Math.toRadians(perHalfDegrees)));

    return Math.max(radius, minRadius);
}

private static Rect computeChildFrame(final int centerX, final int centerY, final int radius, final float degrees,
        final int size) {

    final double childCenterX = centerX + radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    final double childCenterY = centerY + radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees));

    return new Rect((int) (childCenterX - size / 2), (int) (childCenterY - size / 2),
            (int) (childCenterX + size / 2), (int) (childCenterY + size / 2));
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int radius = mRadius = computeRadius(Math.abs(mToDegrees - mFromDegrees), getChildCount(), mChildSize,
            mChildPadding, MIN_RADIUS);
    final int size = radius * 2 + mChildSize + mChildPadding + mLayoutPadding * 2;

    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);

    final int count = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mChildSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mChildSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    final int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
    final int centerY = getHeight() / 2;
    final int radius = mExpanded ? mRadius : 0;

    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final float perDegrees = (mToDegrees - mFromDegrees) / (childCount - 1);

    float degrees = mFromDegrees;
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        Rect frame = computeChildFrame(centerX, centerY, radius, degrees, mChildSize);
        degrees += perDegrees;
        getChildAt(i).layout(frame.left, frame.top, frame.right, frame.bottom);
    }
}

/**
 * refers to {@link LayoutAnimationController#getDelayForView(View view)}
 */
private static long computeStartOffset(final int childCount, final boolean expanded, final int index,
        final float delayPercent, final long duration, Interpolator interpolator) {
    final float delay = delayPercent * duration;
    final long viewDelay = (long) (getTransformedIndex(expanded, childCount, index) * delay);
    final float totalDelay = delay * childCount;

    float normalizedDelay = viewDelay / totalDelay;
    normalizedDelay = interpolator.getInterpolation(normalizedDelay);

    return (long) (normalizedDelay * totalDelay);
}

private static int getTransformedIndex(final boolean expanded, final int count, final int index) {
    if (expanded) {
        return count - 1 - index;
    }

    return index;
}

private static Animation createExpandAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta,
        long startOffset, long duration, Interpolator interpolator) {
    Animation animation = new RotateAndTranslateAnimation(0, toXDelta, 0, toYDelta, 0, 720);
    animation.setStartOffset(startOffset);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    return animation;
}

private static Animation createShrinkAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta,
        long startOffset, long duration, Interpolator interpolator) {
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    animationSet.setFillAfter(true);

    final long preDuration = duration / 2;
    Animation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setStartOffset(startOffset);
    rotateAnimation.setDuration(preDuration);
    rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    animationSet.addAnimation(rotateAnimation);

    Animation translateAnimation = new RotateAndTranslateAnimation(0, toXDelta, 0, toYDelta, 360, 720);
    translateAnimation.setStartOffset(startOffset + preDuration);
    translateAnimation.setDuration(duration - preDuration);
    translateAnimation.setInterpolator(interpolator);
    translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);

    animationSet.addAnimation(translateAnimation);

    return animationSet;
}

private void bindChildAnimation(final View child, final int index, final long duration) {
    final boolean expanded = mExpanded;
    final int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
    final int centerY = getHeight() / 2;
    final int radius = expanded ? 0 : mRadius;

    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final float perDegrees = (mToDegrees - mFromDegrees) / (childCount - 1);
    Rect frame = computeChildFrame(centerX, centerY, radius, mFromDegrees + index * perDegrees, mChildSize);

    final int toXDelta = frame.left - child.getLeft();
    final int toYDelta = frame.top - child.getTop();

    Interpolator interpolator = mExpanded ? new AccelerateInterpolator() : new OvershootInterpolator(1.5f);
    final long startOffset = computeStartOffset(childCount, mExpanded, index, 0.1f, duration, interpolator);

    Animation animation = mExpanded ? createShrinkAnimation(0, toXDelta, 0, toYDelta, startOffset, duration,
            interpolator) : createExpandAnimation(0, toXDelta, 0, toYDelta, startOffset, duration, interpolator);

    final boolean isLast = getTransformedIndex(expanded, childCount, index) == childCount - 1;
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (isLast) {
                postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onAllAnimationsEnd();
                    }
                }, 0);
            }
        }
    });

    child.setAnimation(animation);
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return mExpanded;
}

public void setArc(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees) {
    if (mFromDegrees == fromDegrees && mToDegrees == toDegrees) {
        return;
    }

    mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
    mToDegrees = toDegrees;

    requestLayout();
}

public void setChildSize(int size) {
    if (mChildSize == size || size < 0) {
        return;
    }

    mChildSize = size;

    requestLayout();
}

public int getChildSize() {
    return mChildSize;
}

/**
 * switch between expansion and shrinkage
 * 
 * @param showAnimation
 */
public void switchState(final boolean showAnimation) {
    if (showAnimation) {
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            bindChildAnimation(getChildAt(i), i, 300);
        }
    }

    mExpanded = !mExpanded;

    if (!showAnimation) {
        requestLayout();
    }

    invalidate();
 }

  private void onAllAnimationsEnd() {
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        getChildAt(i).clearAnimation();
    }

    requestLayout();
}

}
```

---

this is the second java file called ArcMenu

```
public class ArcMenu extends RelativeLayout {
private ArcLayout mArcLayout;

private ImageView mHintView;

public ArcMenu(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public ArcMenu(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
    applyAttrs(attrs);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    li.inflate(R.layout.arc_menu, this);

    mArcLayout = (ArcLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_layout);

    final ViewGroup controlLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.control_layout);
    controlLayout.setClickable(true);
    controlLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mHintView.startAnimation(createHintSwitchAnimation(mArcLayout.isExpanded()));
                mArcLayout.switchState(true);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mHintView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.control_hint);
}

private void applyAttrs(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArcLayout, 0, 0);

        float fromDegrees = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ArcLayout_fromDegrees, ArcLayout.DEFAULT_FROM_DEGREES);
        float toDegrees = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ArcLayout_toDegrees, ArcLayout.DEFAULT_TO_DEGREES);
        mArcLayout.setArc(fromDegrees, toDegrees);

        int defaultChildSize = mArcLayout.getChildSize();
        int newChildSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.ArcLayout_childSize, defaultChildSize);
        mArcLayout.setChildSize(newChildSize);

        a.recycle();
    }
}

public void addItem(View item, OnClickListener listener) {
    mArcLayout.addView(item);
    item.setOnClickListener(getItemClickListener(listener));
}

private OnClickListener getItemClickListener(final OnClickListener listener) {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View viewClicked) {
            Animation animation = bindItemAnimation(viewClicked, true, 400);
            animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            itemDidDisappear();
                        }
                    }, 0);
                }
            });

            final int itemCount = mArcLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                View item = mArcLayout.getChildAt(i);
                if (viewClicked != item) {
                    bindItemAnimation(item, false, 300);
                }
            }

            mArcLayout.invalidate();
            mHintView.startAnimation(createHintSwitchAnimation(true));

            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onClick(viewClicked);
            }
        }
    };
}

private Animation bindItemAnimation(final View child, final boolean isClicked, final long duration) {
    Animation animation = createItemDisapperAnimation(duration, isClicked);
    child.setAnimation(animation);

    return animation;
}

private void itemDidDisappear() {
    final int itemCount = mArcLayout.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        View item = mArcLayout.getChildAt(i);
        item.clearAnimation();
    }

    mArcLayout.switchState(false);
}

private static Animation createItemDisapperAnimation(final long duration, final boolean isClicked) {
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animationSet.addAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, isClicked ? 2.0f : 0.0f, 1.0f, isClicked ? 2.0f : 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f));
    animationSet.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f));

    animationSet.setDuration(duration);
    animationSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animationSet.setFillAfter(true);

    return animationSet;
}

private static Animation createHintSwitchAnimation(final boolean expanded) {
    Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(expanded ? 45 : 0, expanded ? 0 : 45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    animation.setStartOffset(0);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    return animation;
}
}
```

---

I think it has something to do with the x and y axes but i'm not sure in which of the java files
   i need to change that or where exactly

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without really looking at the mechanics, simply adjusting the default from & to degrees values in `ArcLayout`  sound promising.

Comment: well,ive tried it all and as i posted below,i found where i had to make the change ,but still not complete,can u see below what im doing wrong?

Comment: ive tried changing the values alot for the margins but it wont go all the way to the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few good hours i figured out where to make the change, its in the XML file for the arc menu

```
       <com.capricorn.ArcMenu
        android:id="@+id/arc_menu_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"       
        android:layout_marginLeft="-210dp"
       a ndroid:layout_marginBottom="-0dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   
        arc:fromDegrees="@dimen/menuFromDegrees"
        arc:toDegrees="@dimen/menuToDegrees"
        arc:childSize="@dimen/menuChildSize"/>
```

but i got it as far as left side of the screen.,still having trouble getting it at bottom of screen it's hanging out kind of in the middle far left of screen no matter what i do

Comment: had to change the values in the dimensions ,menuToDegrees and menuChildSize,changed them in my dimensions xml in the values folder,changed child size to 50dp,changed to degrees to 360.0,changed from degrees to 270.0,that pushed the menu to the left side,then in the layout changed the layout margin left and bottom untill i achieved the right position,leaving it at negative though